# Unable to resolve react-native-swiper

Tags: react-native, react-native-swiper

Relatively new to react native. Issued the following commmands to create a new react native project:

> create-react-native-app SwiperExample
>     cd SwiperExample
>     npm install --save react-native-swipe-gestures

I modified App.js and included

> import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper';

When I go to test using npm start, I the following error:

> Unable to resolve react-native-swiper" from "./C:\Users\sue\ReactNativeApps\SwiperExample\App.js"
>   Failed building JavaScript bundle

My package.json include the following dependecies

> "dependencies": {
>      "expo": "^25.0.0",
>      "react": "16.2.0",
>      "react-native": "0.52.0",
>      "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.2"
>    }

Any suggestions what is wrong?

Comment: It sounds like you are mixing up two different libraries? [1](https://github.com/glepur/react-native-swipe-gestures), [2](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a wrong import
Change this

```
import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper';
```

By

```
import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper-gestures';
```

Or install the correct package in case you installed the wrong one

```
npm install --save react-native-swipe
```

Comment: That seems logical but a few things <br>

Comment: That seems logical but the instructions say to just use import react-native-swiper and I have it working at expo.io/snacks with just react-native-swiper. I believe it has something to do with my local setup but can't figure it out.

Comment: Look, seems that you've installed the wrong library try installing:` npm install --save react-native-swipe` and your import will work :)